# Next.js/React - How to universally resolve the user language, from an Apollo client HOC?

Tags: javascript, next.js, react-apollo, apollo-client, high-order-component

I'm working on a I18n module using the Next.js framework (v5).

In order to display the UI on the user's default language, I'm trying to figure out what that language is, *universally*.

Resolving the language from the browser is "fairly simple", but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do that on the server side, **while** providing that value to a HOC that wraps my Page, so that I can specify in my request `headers` the locale to use, in order to fetch content in that language.

I figured out how to resolve the user's language from the server, using the `accept-language` header, in the `pages/_documents.js`:

```
  static getInitialProps(props) {
    const { req, res, renderPage, isServer = false } = props;
    const cookies = new Cookies();

    if (isServer) {
      const headers = req.headers;
      const acceptedUserLanguages = acceptLanguageParser.parse(headers['accept-language']);
      const mostPreferredLanguage = get(acceptedUserLanguages, '[0]', {});
      // {code: 'en', region: 'GB'}
```

This works fine.

But, I need to access this `mostPreferredLanguage` within my HOC that wraps the Page component, and I really don't know how to do that, because the HOC code is executed **before** the `getInitialProps` function. And I don't have access to `req.headers` from the HOC itself, as far as I know.

HOC implementation:

```
export default withData(
  compose(
    withRedux(configureStore),
    withLoanAdvisor,
    graphql(institutionPagesData, {
      options: (props) => {
        return {
          context: {
            headers: {
              'gcms-locale': 'FR', // How do I universally get the user language here? I don't have access to request.headers there
              'gcms-locale-no-default': false
            },
          },
        };
      },
    }),
  )(SchoolPage));
```

---

### Potential solutions

#### Redux

I've been thinking about using **Redux**. I tried to implement it but got blocked as it doesn't seem possible to use Redux on the server side.

The idea with Redux was to use `getInitialProps` to resolve the language and store it in redux, then I'd connect to the store before running my `graphql()` HOC query, therefore making the language available in the `props` of the `graphql` HOC, so that I could run the query with the correct headers.

But as mentioned, Redux isn't available on the server side and trying to initialise it through `_document.js` crashes the server. See https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/3990#issuecomment-372159451

#### Cookies

I also tried using cookies, but while I was successful reading cookies from both browser/server, I wasn't able to write them on the server side inside the `_document.js` `getInitialProps` function. I don't know why though, and [existing examples](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/af7d021d48c30e5c78e1022e2458d58e4d1e7753/examples/with-cookie-auth) didn't help me out.

Answer (score 3):

You can access `getInitialProps` from HOCs - the restrictions on `getInitialProps` apply as usual (no children components, only `pages`), but it's quite common pattern, e.g.:

```
const withSize = (WrappedComponent) => {
  return class extends React.Component {
    static async getInitialProps({ req }) {
      const ua = req ? req.headers['user-agent'] : navigator.userAgent;
      const userAgent = uaParser(ua);

      return { userAgent };
    }

    // ... implementation

    render() {
      // userAgent meant to be removed from props
      const { userAgent, ...props } = this.props || {};
      return (
        <WrappedComponent
          {...props}
          {...this.state}
          isMobile={this.state.windowWidth <= deviceWidth.mobile}
          isTablet={this.state.windowWidth <= deviceWidth.tablet}
        />
      );
    }
  };
};
```

See nextjs's examples for further examples, e.g. https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/3e51ddb8af55b6438aa3aeb382081b9a1c86f325/examples/with-lingui/components/withLang.js.

(Don't forget to `hoistNonReactStatics` if you want to use `getInitialProps` yet in the components wrapped by the HOC.)